# Why is Maven compiling/running the wrong code?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm working on a web application (Apache Tomcat 7). The project is configured as a Maven project. I don't know why but sometimes when I try to run my code it seams to be compiling/running an older version of my project or something.

The thing is that if I run my code from the command line (executing: `mvn clean tomcat7:run`) it works fine. The problem comes when I try to do the same thing inside IntelliJ IDEA. I've configured a run configuration to do so but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: Solved: Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys. I solved the problem. It had nothing to do with Maven. IntelliJ configured the project with a different encoding and when I tried to run my project from IntelliJ it looked like very strange. I changed the encoding to UTF-8 and now it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to pure code, but to environment variables / settings.

```
Go do Run > Edit Configurations 
Look for Command Line: > enter the value clean install
Hit Apply > OK > Run your code again
```

Comment: Hi, at the moment I have this on command line: `clean tomcat7:run`

Comment: So try changing it into 'clean install' only